# Question on chgrp

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions

I have a small requirement here. I have a directory with a lot of files. There are certain number of files which belong to X group and certain number of files which belong Y group. Now, my requirement is to convert the files belonging to X group to Y group.

How quickly this can be done ? I assuming I might have to use xargs command. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should take care of it:

```
find . -group X_GNAME -exec chgrp Y_GNAME {} +
```

Obviously, make sure you replace `X_GNAME` with the old group name, and `Y_GNAME` with the new group name, and possibly `.` with the base path, if you're not in the correct directory.

See the `find` man page for more information.

Comment: The same way, just using the syntax for `chown`.

Comment: But find does not have option for finding the file by owner rite ?